# I am attempting to cleanup Captcha Images but pytesseract fails to recognize them

Tags: computer-vision, python-imaging-library, ocr, captcha, python-tesseract

I am applying the following operations to convert the original captcha to what i believe is more readable

I applied median filter, converted it to grayscale, sharpened it but pytesseract still returns empty string.

following operations were applied

```
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img = img.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter())
img = ImageOps.grayscale(img)
img = img.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
img = img.filter(ImageFilter.MaxFilter(3))
img = img.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
img = img.point(lambda x: 0 if x < 180 else 255, '1')
```

[Original Captcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqHIC.png)
[Converted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGwHQ.png)

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(
    img,
    config='--psm 6 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
)
```

returns empty string